# How should I store a collection of objects and provide specific methods to query them?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios, collections

I need some advise on the best way to achive the following:

- Store a collection of a specific type of objects in order
- Custom methods to search the collection
- Other custom methods for returning objects from the collection based on some rules
- Need instance variables to keep track of things in the collection

Originally I was thinking about sub classing the NSMutableArray class and adding the extra methods and variables that I want that are specific to the objects that I'm going to be storing in the array, but the Apple docs said this was a no no!

I know that you can use `Categories` but they don't support adding instance variables which I need to keep track of elements in the collection.

Also I don't want these extra methods being adding to all NSMutableArray objects just my custom one.

What is the best way to do this, the idea is to have a nice wrapper around NSMutableArray to query my custom objects and manipulate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class (inheriting from `NSObject`) that contains a `NSMutableArray`. Write your own custom `add:` and `remove...` methods to add and remove objects from the array.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a class with an NSMutableArray instance variable. Store your objects in there. Implement your methods on that class.